# Reproducible LaTeX Environment

Tags: installing

I have a school of a few hundreds of computers running Microsoft Windows (without taking into account the fact that many come with their own personal device also running Windows).

How can i deploy on all computers an identical environment of LaTeX (meaning with all exact packages release number)?

The solution must also work if we get a new computer in 1 year, 2 years or more... We will have to install everytime an identical environment with the same release number of all used packages (tikz, pgfplot, amsmath and a few hundreds of others).

Thanks for your help

Comment: And why don't you just use overleaf.com instead?

Comment: For example, use a network device mounted to the same directory on every machine or automatically copy an installation from a network device to every machine. This can be done automatically, e.g., using active directory. And don't forget to do a full installation. Otherwise MiKTeX could install packages on the fly and will do this with the current version of the time of first usage.

Comment: Are you planning to perform updates at all, or not? If you install the latest version of MikTeX today and you keep it up to date on all your machines, then you can install the then-latest version once you add a machine in the future and it will use the same versions as your existing installations.

Comment: Or if you want a fixed version you can download a TeX Live release from the 'historic' repository, for example https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2022/ contains a version dated 21st of March 2022. This version contains a frozen set of packages. TeX Live was developed for Unix/Linux originally but it also supports Windows (see `install-tl-windows.bat` in the `install-tl.zip` archive on that repository.

Comment: @daleif Cloud technologies like Overleaf are not tolerated by our government.

Comment: @cabohah Most students have a personal device not all the time connected to a network drive nor linked to Active Directory.

Comment: @Marijn Texlive is far from containing all packages we need. So we can't use this solution.

Comment: @VincentISOZ TeX Live contains all of CTAN (with the exception of a very small number of packages that have an incompatible license), so that is a very complete distribution.

Comment: Regarding the personal devices: either you manage them or you don't manage them. If you do then you can control installations and updates, maybe with a few days delay here and there if a student is not connected. If you don't manage them then it is practically unavoidable that you will end up with different versions. However, this might not be such a big problem, almost all the important packages are stable and backwards compatible, so most of the time you will not even notice that the versions are different.

Comment: What packages do you need that are not in TeXLive as found in the historic repository?

Comment: "Texlive is far from containing all packages we need." seems very unlikely but in any case texlive has no installation requirements outside the texlive directory so if you install on one machine then zip up `texlive/2022` you can distribute that to your users in whatever way you want. all they have to do is extract the files from the zip

Comment: If the user's devices are not attached to the network, you could at most provide a USB device with a copy of the network files. However, if you cannot force the users to copy this device, you cannot force them to use your versions of packages. In this case the best you can do is to keep your TeX distribution up-to-date and tell the users, they should do the same, if they have any problem you don't have and your cannot reproduce with your up-to-date installation.

Comment: The normal practice, as I understand it, for a large number of networked computers is for the IT folks to manage the content from a central server that handles everything for you on the individual machines, whether pushing a "permanently fixed" version (a bad idea, I think) or a periodically updated version of TeXLive or MiKTeX or any other software distribution. For students' individual machines, the  IT department could provide the download (if TeX license allows), providing a fixed version at any particular time; or could point to the CTAN download, providing the current version.